# Python/Django: How to make sure "string".upper and "string".lower work with different languages?

Tags: python, django, localization

I have a problem with upper and lower functions in Python/Django. I have the following line of code:

`UserInfo.objects.get(id=user_id).city.upper()`

The problem is that some of the Turkish users let me know that they are seeing the wrong information. For example one of them is from a city called "izmir". The upper function converts that into "IZMIR" it turns out the actual result should be "İZMİR".

What is the right way to use `upper` or `lower` functions for any given language? I read about changing the server locale as an answer. Changing server locale for each user request does not make sense to me. What about multi-threaded applications that handle different users simultaneously?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: If there are accents in the uppercase word, then there should be accents in the lowercase word too. There's no way to tell that a certain Latin letter should be converted to a different Turkish letter.

Comment: @MattDMo: note that Unicode `CaseFolding.txt` file has also such rule. I would be surprised if Unicode Standard doesn't include it from first version). @ OP and other: the exception in Unicode are only on `tr` and `az` (and possible other "Turkic languages"): few exceptions, because upper/lower exists just in few scripts (other scripts have very different problems)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use [PyICU](https://pypi.org/project/PyICU/)

```
>>> from icu import UnicodeString, Locale
>>> tr = Locale("TR")
>>> s = UnicodeString("I")
>>> print(unicode(s.toLower(tr)))
ı
>>> s = UnicodeString("i")
>>> print(unicode(s.toUpper(tr)))
İ
```

Firstly ask your user to select his preferred language and convert his city to that's language in uppercase.